# Change figure environment options

Tags: org-mode, latex

It is possible to change the figure options for a latex figure in org-mode?
Currently I'm using the following to insert a figure in my org document.

```
#+CAPTION: awesome figure
#+NAME: fig:my-figure
[[file:awesome-figure.png]]
```

This is exported to

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[ ... ]{awesome-figure.png}
\caption{\label{fig:my-figure}awesome-figure}
\end{figure}
```

This is already quite good, but it tells latex not to try and enforce the `[htb]` hints. How can I change it so that latex figures are exported as follows?

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\inclduegraphics[ ... ]{awesome-figure.png}
\caption{\label{fig:my-figure}awesome-figure}
\end{figure}
```

The exclamation mark for the figure options is important since it tells latex it should enforce the figure placement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Modify `org-latex-default-figure-position` to change the default, or use the following on the specific elements,

```
 #+attr_latex: :placement [!tbh]
```